# How to return the `form` as invalid?

Tags: angularjs

I am comparing `password` field and 'repassword`fields. when user wrongly types even in`repassword`fields i am throwing error. But the`submit` button enables..

I understand that, i required to make the form became `$invalid` how to do that? instead of testing the variable in the 'ng-disbaled' in the submit button?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.myFormDetails = function ( userInfo ) {
    
    console.log( userInfo );
    
  }
  
});
```

```css
label{
  display:block;
  padding:1em;
}

span.error{
  display:block;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    
    <form name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="myFormDetails(userInfo)">
      
      <label for="password">
        Enter Password
        <input type="password" ng-pattern="/^[^\s]+$/" name="password" ng-model="userInfo.password" id="password" required>
        <span class="error"  
          ng-show="myForm.password.$dirty && !myForm.password.$valid">
            Please Provide Valid Password
          </span>
      </label>
      
      <label for="password">
        Re-Enter Password
        <input type="password" name="repassword" id="repassword" ng-model="userInfo.repassword" required>
        <span class="error" 
        ng-show="myForm.repassword.$dirty &&
          (userInfo.password != userInfo.repassword || myForm.repassword.$invalid)">
          Password not matching
      </span>
      </label>
      <label for="submit">
        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
      </label>
    </form>
    
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take off the novalidate attribute in the form tag.

It specifies that the form-data (input) should not be validated when submitted.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.myFormDetails = function ( userInfo ) {
    
    console.log( userInfo );
    
  }
  
});
```

```css
label{
  display:block;
  padding:1em;
}

span.error{
  display:block;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    
    <form name="myForm" ng-submit="myFormDetails(userInfo)">
      
      <label for="password">
        Enter Password
        <input type="password" ng-pattern="/^[^\s]+$/" name="password" ng-model="userInfo.password" id="password" required>
        <span class="error"  
          ng-show="myForm.password.$dirty && !myForm.password.$valid">
            Please Provide Valid Password
          </span>
      </label>
      
      <label for="password">
        Re-Enter Password
        <input type="password" name="repassword" id="repassword" ng-model="userInfo.repassword" required>
        <span class="error" 
        ng-show="myForm.repassword.$dirty &&
          (userInfo.password != userInfo.repassword || myForm.repassword.$invalid)">
          Password not matching
      </span>
      </label>
      <label for="submit">
        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="userInfo.password != userInfo.repassword || myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
      </label>
    </form>
    
  </div>
```

Comment: But removing that, I am finding the `html5` error marks in firefox

Comment: I tried in the chrome. I am not shore aboute firefox. But if you keep novalidate the form doesn't validate.
novalidate is only html5 attribute and supported for firefox 4.0